# Road Emission Calculator - QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, road

I managed to install the Road Emission Calculator plugin in earlier version of QGIS. Unfortunately, it's not showing me results.
Had anyone tried this plugin?
[image]

Comment: do you have the external libraries required? EmissionCalculatorLib https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/RoadEmissionCalculator/

Comment: Yes I add this plugin in qgis version 3.0 because the plug in was not compatible to qgis 3.26 I used to have.

Comment: I dowloaded the zip file in the qgis plugin website you mentioned. I add the plugin from the zip file